# Return ID based on group values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

For a sample subset of a table t1

```
+----+------+
| ID | Flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  1 |    0 |
|  1 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  3 |    1 |
|  3 |    1 |
|  3 |    0 |
+----+------+
```

I need to extract ID's based on Flag values in two different ways:

1) All ID's with no 1's in Flag.

```
    +----+
    | ID |
    +----+
    |  2 |
    +----+
```

2) All ID's with more than one 1's in Flag.

```
    +----+
    | ID |
    +----+
    |  3 |
    +----+
```

Attempted query isn't useful hence excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way of achieving this is using case aggregation. For example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Flag BIT);
INSERT @T VALUES (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 0);

SELECT ID
FROM @T
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0; -- No flag 1.

SELECT ID
FROM @T
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN 1 END) > 1; -- More than one flag 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case bit of code, since the flag is numeric and a 1 or 0.

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE
        WHEN Ones = 0
            Then 'No active flags'
        When Ones > 1 
            Then 'Multiple Active flags'
    END
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
       Sum(Cast(Flag as int)) as Ones 
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY ID 
    ) as Src
WHERE Ones != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to check the total of count of flag.

1)

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(flag) cnt
  FROM t1  
 GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(flag) = 0
```

Result

```
id  cnt
2   0
```

2)

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(flag) cnt
  FROM t1  
 GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(flag) > 1
```

Result

```
id  cnt
3   2
```

Comment: pls. check in above Query with Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: was it bit data type?

Comment: It was. Thanks for pointing that out. Good to know that bit can't be summed.  CAST to int would make this work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your flags are numeric and only have values of 1 and 0, then you can use the following two queries:

```
select ID from t1 group by ID having sum(cast(flag as int)) = 0;
```

and

```
select ID from t1 group by ID having sum(cast(flag as int)) > 1;
```

Comment: pls. check in above Query with Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: A simple cast on the the flag to int will fix that.  I did specify "As long as your flags are numeric" a bit data type isn't really numeric it's a logical data type.  Numeric data types work with traditional numeric operations such as addition and by extension aggregates such as SUM.